# Solving $e^{e^z}=1$: am I missing something?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I solved the equation $e^{e^z}=1$ and it seemed to easy so I suspect I must be missing something.

> Would someone please check my answer?

My original answer:

$e^{e^z}=1$ if and only if $e^z = 2\pi i k$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$ if and only if $z=\ln(2\pi i k)$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$.

**Edit**

After reading the comments and answers I tried to do it again. Unfortunately, I still do not get the same result as in the answers.

**My second attempt:**

We have

$$ e^x = 1 \iff x = 2 \pi i k$$

hence

$$ e^z = 2 \pi i k$$

for some $k$ in $\mathbb Z$.

Letting $e^z = e^x (\cos y + i \sin y)$ we get

$$ e^x \cos y + i e^x \sin y = 2 \pi k i$$

which implies that $\cos y = 0$ which happens if and only if $y_j = {\pi \over 2} + \pi j$ where $j\in \mathbb Z$. At $y_j$ we have
$\sin y = \pm 1$ hence if $j$ is even

$$ e^x = 2 \pi i k$$

and if $j$ is odd

$$ e^x = -2 \pi i k$$

Hence if $j$ is even,

$$ x = {\pi \over 2} + \ln(2 \pi k)$$

and if $j$ is odd,

$$ x = {3\pi \over 2} + \ln(2 \pi k)$$

So we see that the solutions are

$$
z_{t,k}=\begin{cases}
 {\pi \over 2} + \ln(2 \pi k) + i ({\pi \over 2} + 2t \pi )\\ 
 {3\pi \over 2} + \ln(2 \pi k) + i({\pi \over 2} + (2 +1)t \pi )
\end{cases} 
$$
for $k,t \in \mathbb Z$.

> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if $k=0$? Also, which branch cut of the logarithm are you taking?

Comment: You'd need to consider the above statement by @5xum and then consider the solutions when $k<0$ and $k>0$.

Comment: I do not think my comment to YouMath should have been removed.

Comment: (1) You aren't considering the sign of $k$ (you are assuming it is positive); (2) Your "$x=\frac{\pi}{2}+\cdots$" is wrong (should have "$x=\frac{\pi}{2}i +\cdots$" instead), likewise for the other case; (3) Your "$(2+1)t\pi$" is wrong (perhaps "$(2t+1)\pi$" ?); (4) You seem to be using the symbol $x$ for two completely different things -- you should choose another name for it at the top, perhaps.

Comment: @MPW Thank you for your comment. I'll try again.

Comment: @MPW You are right. I missed a $t$ there. It is a typo. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your expression "$\ln 2\pi ik$" is multivalued (worse, it is undefined if $k=0$).

One may write $$e^{e^z}=1 \iff e^z = 2\pi i k \stackrel{k\neq 0}{\iff} z =
\begin{cases}
\ln 2\pi k + \frac{\pi i}{2}(4n+1), & k>0\\
\ln -2\pi k + \frac{\pi i}{2}(4n-1), & k<0
\end{cases}$$

So the solutions are $$z_{n,k} = \ln2\pi |k| + \frac{\pi i}{2}\left(4n+\frac{k}{|k|}\right)$$ for integral $n$ and nonzero integral $k$, and "$\ln$" is the real-valued function of a positive real variable (note that since $k$ is nonzero, one has that $\frac{k}{|k|} = \pm 1$ according to the sign of $k$).

Comment: This is only valid for positive $k$.

Comment: @Wood: Hmm, you're right. I'll correct it. I wrote too fast.

Comment: @Wood: Fixed. +1 for the tip.

Comment: I tried to do it again but I am getting a different result from yours. I added my complete solution into the question.

Comment: I don't see my mistake.

Comment: @student: see my comment on your question

Answer (score 5):

Since $1$ can be written $1=e^0$ it follows that a first solution is
$$e^z=i2\pi k,\qquad (k \in \mathbb{Z})$$

If $k=0$ there are no solutions since $e^z$ is never zero.

If $k>0$ write $i2 \pi k$ in exponential polar form and you should find that
$$|i2 \pi k|=2 \pi |k| = 2 \pi k, \qquad (\text{since $k>0$})$$

So
\begin{align}
i 2 \pi k &= e^{i \pi /2}e^{\ln(2 \pi k)} \\
          &= e^{i \pi /2 + \ln(2 \pi k)}
\end{align}
Hence solution for $k>0$ is of the form
$$z=\ln(2 \pi k)+i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2 \pi n \right), \qquad \text{for $n \in \mathbb{Z}, k \in \mathbb{Z} \cap (0, + \infty)$}$$

I leave the case $k < 0$ as an exercise for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are making too many jumps

Consider that in Approach 1 you said

> 1. $e^{e^z}=1$ if and only if $e^z = 2\pi i k$
> 2. $e^z = 2\pi i k$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$ if and only if $z=\ln(2\pi i k)$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$

and in Approach 2, you said

> $$ e^x = 1 \iff x = 2 \pi i k$$
>
> hence
>
> $$ e^z = 2 \pi i k$$

---

Of course we see now that [(2) is wrong](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1946466/140308). While (1) is right (Or not?), (1) seems like [cheating death (or cheating vanishment-in-a-puff-of-logic)](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/God#Final_Proof_of_the_Non-Existence_of_God). You're assuming $e^{iy}$ and $e^z$ behave too similarly, if not outright the same, to $e^x$. I suggest you expand $e^{e^z}$ by definition instead of making jumps as to which term should equal some multiple of $\pi$.

Let's start with the $z$:

$$e^{e^z}= e^{e^{x+iy}}$$

and the inner $e^z = e^{x+iy}$:

$$e^{e^{x+iy}}=e^{e^{x}e^{iy}}$$

Now for the $e^{iy}$:

$$e^{e^{x}e^{iy}}=  e^{e^{x}(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))}=e^{e^{x}\cos(y)+ie^{x}\sin(y)}$$

Let's proceed to the outer $e^{f(x,y)+ig(x,y)}$:

$$e^{e^{x}\cos(y)+ie^{x}\sin(y)}=e^{e^{x}\cos(y)}e^{ie^{x}\sin(y)} $$

Now for the $e^{ig(x,y)}$:

$$e^{e^{x}\cos(y)}e^{ie^{x}\sin(y)}= e^{e^{x}\cos(y)}(\cos(e^{x}\sin(y))+i\sin(e^{x}\sin(y)))$$

Finally, we can bring in the 1:

$$e^{e^{x}\cos(y)}(\cos(e^{x}\sin(y))+i\sin(e^{x}\sin(y))) = e^{e^{x}\cos(y)}\cos(e^{x}\sin(y))+ie^{e^{x}\cos(y)}\sin(e^{x}\sin(y)) = 1+0i$$

$$\iff e^{e^{x}\cos(y)}\cos(e^{x}\sin(y)) = 1, e^{e^{x}\cos(y)}\sin(e^{x}\sin(y)) = 0$$

$\therefore,$ we reduce a complex equation into a system of 2 real equations, whose solutions are:

$$(x,y) = (\ln(2m \pi),\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 l \pi)$$

This can be shown to be equivalent to [WA's answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7Be%5Ez%7D%3D1):

$$z = 2 \pi i n_2 + \ln(2 i \pi n_1)$$